# adding ssh key to heroku buildpack

Tags: heroku, buildpack

i have an internal developer tool that i've pushed to heroku that is basically a form entry app that feeds the inputted data to a shell script to set up a remote server environment. one thing i'd like to do is add the generated code to a git repo at the end. however, i'm not sure if i can securely get an ssh key onto the heroku dyno.

as far as i can tell i could stick an ssh key in a buildpack and have it copied to `/app/.ssh` pretty easily but this means putting the ssh key on github in a forked (public) repo. is there any good way to handle this or is heroku just not meant for this use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing private ssh deploy keys on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961970/installing-private-ssh-deploy-keys-on-heroku)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i realized i think i can put the ssh key in the git repo that's pushed to heroku. worst case i can specify a an `/app/.ssh/config` file in a custom buildpack that points to an identityFile. not sure why it took me so long to realize this.